# Vue.js cannot find element from template folder

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, vue.js

i am building an app with cordova, ionic and <s>angular</s> vue.js.
I have an template folder with html files which includes my ion-view to the index.html.

But now i have the problem that i cannot get elements about the id of html tags from this template files..

My vue.js is running. So that is not the problem. I can include vue.js data into the index.html but not into the html files from the templates folder.

Here is my file structure

[image]

and this is my vue js code from the vuestuff.js file. The div with the id #inputWrapper is inside my liste.html file in the template folder.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#inputWrapper',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

here is my html code:

```
<ion-footer-bar>
    <div id="inputWrapper">
      <input id="entryInput" type="text" ng-focus="1==1" placeholder="Eintrag"><span><button class="" > Add </button></span>
    </div>
  </ion-footer-bar>
```

i hope you could help me :)

Comment: where do you want to refer html elements and give a sample html

Comment: i updated the post and added my html code. 
i think the problem is that i try to bind a div element which is inside a non html tag like <ion-footer-bar>

Comment: I don't understand. where are you seeing the error?